# Netsuite Transaction search performance

Tags: netsuite

I am using Netsuite API (version v2016_2) to search data. With below code, it seems that Netsuite taking much time to give response for the query. I am searching GL transaction of periticular period that has 149 MainLine record and 3941 LineItem (Journal Entries) record and Netsuite takes almost 22 minutes to give this data in response. Below is code snippet that I am using to search transaction.

```
public void GetTransactionData()
{
        DataTable dtData = new DataTable();
        string errorMsg = "";
        LoginToService(ref errorMsg);

        TransactionSearch objTransSearch = new TransactionSearch();
        TransactionSearchBasic objTransSearchBasic = new TransactionSearchBasic();
        SearchEnumMultiSelectField semsf = new SearchEnumMultiSelectField();

        semsf.@operator = SearchEnumMultiSelectFieldOperator.anyOf;
        semsf.operatorSpecified = true;
        semsf.searchValue = new string[] { "Journal" };
        objTransSearchBasic.type = semsf;


        objTransSearchBasic.postingPeriod = new RecordRef() { internalId = "43" };

        objTransSearch.basic = objTransSearchBasic;


        //Set Search Preferences
        SearchPreferences _searchPreferences = new SearchPreferences();
        Preferences _prefs = new Preferences();
        _serviceInstance.preferences = _prefs;
        _serviceInstance.searchPreferences = _searchPreferences;
        _searchPreferences.pageSize = 1000;
        _searchPreferences.pageSizeSpecified = true;
        _searchPreferences.bodyFieldsOnly = false;

        //Set Search Preferences

        try
        {
            SearchResult result = _serviceInstance.search(objTransSearch);
    /*
    Above line taking almost 22 minutes for below record count 
    result.recordList.Length = 149
    Total JournalEntryLine = 3941
    */


            List<JournalEntry> lstJEntry = new List<JournalEntry>();
            List<JournalEntryLine> lstLineItems = new List<JournalEntryLine>();

            if (result.status.isSuccess)
            {
                for (int i = 0; i <= result.recordList.Length - 1; i += 1)
                {

                    JournalEntry JEntry = (JournalEntry)result.recordList[i];
                    lstJEntry.Add((JournalEntry)result.recordList[i]);

                    if (JEntry.lineList != null)
                    {

                        foreach (JournalEntryLine line in JEntry.lineList.line)
                        {
                            lstLineItems.Add(line);
                        }
                    }
                }
            }


            try
            {
                _serviceInstance.logout();
            }
            catch (Exception ex)
            {

            }
        }

        catch (Exception ex)
        {
            throw ex;
        }
    }
```

I am unable to know that If I am missing something in my code or this is something about the data. Please suggest me some sort of solution for this.

Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

You should set _searchPreferences.bodyFieldsOnly = true. It will improve the performance with searching because it doesn't return the related or sublist data

Answer (score 0):

I think you are doing this search from the outside of the Netsuite to get journal entries data or lines. Instead of doing a direct search outside, do maintain RESTLET in NETSUITE and call that RESTLET. In the RESTLET DO that search you wanted and return results. Within the NETSUITE, search performance gives fast results.